# How to move object by a specific distance in Inkscape

Tags: inkscape, transform

I draw a circle of 150px diameter in Inkscape，Now I want to move this circle, for example, upward exactly 45px. How to do it in Inkscape?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Select the object, and then open the *Object→Transfrom* dialog, and select the *Move* tab.

There you have options for moving horizontally or vertically, in several units.

Documentation [here](http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html/Transforms.html#Transforms-Transform).

Answer (score 9):

Just modify the `Y` value in the toolbar, *adding* 45 to move the element up.

[image: Toolbar]

If you don't want to calculate, you can even add `+ 45 px`, inkscape will do the math for you.

Answer (score 3):

For example:

- Mark the object.
- Open the XML-Editor.
- Select cy
- reduce the value by 45
- Hit the Button "Set" or how it is called in your language.

(assuming your settings are in px).